# makefile with many source folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, compilation

The original makefile I have, which works, only involves one source folder and the makefile is stored inside this folder. Now I have multiple folders inside my src folder.

I am using an autogeneration script to work out dependencies and objective files. Each subfolder has a Make-deps and Make-objs file. These are generated from the $(AUTOGEN) command

Before I had this:

```
deps:
    $(AUTOGEN) -d -s $(SRCDIR) -f ../scripts/fgenrc             ;\
    sed -i "" -e's/(SRCDIR)/(OBJDIR)/'                Make-objs ; \
    sed -i "" -e's/(SRCDIR)\(.*\)\.o/(OBJDIR)\1\.o/g' Make-deps ; \
```

So $(AUTOGEN) is just the shell script which makes the dependencies and $(SRCDIR) is where the source files are. Make-obj and Make-deps are the files containing the dependencies and objective file names. 
Somewhere else I have the following:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f Makefile
       @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(POPTIONS) -o $@ $<
```

Now I want to this but where my %.f files are in various folders, and also where I have several Make-obj and Make-deps.

Maybe I should show an example of Make-obs and Make-deps:

**Make-deps:**

```
$(OBJDIR)/fluxes.o fluxes.o: \
    path/to/src/folder1/fluxes.f90 \
    $(OBJDIR)/mod.o \


$(OBJDIR)/ig.o ig.o: \
    path/to/src/folder1/ig.f90 \
    $(OBJDIR)/mod.o \
```

from the `sed` command I change the objective file path to be $(OBJDIR) because this is where I move them when being compiled.

**Make-obj**

```
OBJS = \
    $(OBJDIR)/fluxes.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ig.o \
```

Now I have defined

```
SOURCE_FILES_c   := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c')
SOURCE_FILES_f90 := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.f90')
```

which are all source files found the SRCDIR and its subfolders. Also I have defined

```
DEPS_FILES        := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name 'Makefile-deps')
OBJS_FILES        := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name 'Makefile-objs')
```

which are all dependency and objective files. These are found in each subfolder containing some source code.

Then, I am trying to do following. (The target deps seems to work as when I comment out the compilation rule it does create the deps and objs file correctly in each folder.)

```
code:   create_dir deps scripts
     @make -j $(CORES) $(NAMEEXE)

$(NAMEEXE):   $(LIBRARY) $(OBJS)
        @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(OPTIONS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$(MAIN).o main/$(MAIN).f90
        @$(F90) -o $(NAMEEXE) $(LOPTIONS) $(OBJS) $(LIBRARY)       &&  \

deps:   
        ${AUTOGEN} -d $(AUTOGEN_COMMAND) -f ${AUTOCONF}                   ; \
        $(SEDI) -e "s/[(][^)]*[)]/\$$(OBJDIR)/g" $(OBJS_FILES)               ; \
        $(SEDI) -e "s/[(][^)]*[)]\(.*\)\.o/\$$(OBJDIR)\1\.o/g" 
$(DEPS_FILES) ; \
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_FILES_f:.f90=.o) Makefile
       @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(POPTIONS) -o $@ $<                       &&  \
        ( mv -f *.mod $(OBJDIR) > /dev/null 2>&1;
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_FILES_c:.c=.o) Makefile
       @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(POPTIONS) -o $@ $<                       &&  \
        ( mv -f *.mod $(OBJDIR) > /dev/null 2>&1;
%.o:        $(SOURCE_FILES_c:.c=.o) Makefile
       @make $(OBJDIR)/$@
%.o:        $(SOURCE_FILES_c:.c=.f90) Makefile
       @make $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

I am including the deps and objs by this command

```
-include $(DEPS_FILES)
-include $(OBJS_FILES)
```

I obviously did not want put the entire makefile here, but if something is missing before you can understand what's going on please let me know.

When I type make the error I get is that my $(main) source file cannot open the compiled module file which is included in the main source.
This is because it is not compiled, but this also means that my dependency file is not working as intended? 
When I look into my corresponding dep file which includes the main file, I can see that the dependency modules are added to the source file

Comment: You seem to have four problems: 1) understand how your `deps` rule works, 2) get it to write many `Make-objs` and `Make-deps` files, 3) get make to read all of those files, 4) get Make to find and use source files in many subdirectories. Which of these problems do you need help with, and what progress have you made?

Comment: 1,2  are done. My problem now is that in the deps and objs file I have SRCDIRXX where XX is the nth folder. It orders them after the variable in my makefile which contains all subfolders. So I have a $FOLDER which contains [folder1 folder2...]. I struggling to find a way to define the corresponding SRCDIRXX to contain the path to the subfolders so my makefile knows what to do when reading deps and objs file

Comment: Let me get this straight. You have a variable `FOLDER` which contains e.g. [foo, bar, baz], and in your `Make-objs` and `Make-deps` files you have things like "SRCDIR02" (which means `bar/`), is that right?

Comment: The sed command you don't understand substitutes the string `(SRCDIR)` for the string `(OBJDIR)` in file `Make-objs` (note that the `""` after the `-i` option is useless). The rest of your question is not clear enough to me for answering.

Comment: @Beta yes that is right.. Is there a way to workaround this in the makefile or is it just easier for me to try to hack the autogeneration code in order to let it write the physical path instead of the SRDIRXX

Comment: This line `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_FILES_c) Makefile` appears to make a single object file dependent on every source file in your project.  I'm not sure why a special make deps autogen command is needed instead of using deps generated by the compiler (unless it doesn't support that option) and a simpler Makefile being used.  Also `%.o` doesn't seem to generate an object file in the current directory so it'll always kick off a compile for everything every time you type make.

Comment: Correcting the autogen code is the correct approach. It is possible to work around it in the makefile, but that is a kludge.